# org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException what do I need to change?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The text of exception says "No property fid found for type" (sic!), I tried to google but got nothing for that. Probably it stands for "feature id", but I'm not sure what's going on with it anyway. How do I fix it? Is there something wrong with my class?

My Attribute class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LAB3_ATTRIBUTES")
public class Attribute {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "ATTR_ID", length = 10, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
private ObjectType objectType;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "attribute", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Parameter> parameters;

public Attribute() {
}

public Attribute(String name, ObjectType objectType) {
    this.name = name;
    this.objectType = objectType;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ObjectType getObjectType() {
    return objectType;
}

public void setObjectType(ObjectType objectType) {
    this.objectType = objectType;
}

public List<Parameter> getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}

public void setParameters(List<Parameter> parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}
}
```

My AttributeRepository interface:

```
public interface AttributeRepository extends JpaRepository<Attribute, Integer > {

    Attribute findById(int id);
    List<Attribute> findByName(String name);
    List<Attribute> fidByObjectType(ObjectType objectType);
}
```

My AttributeService interface:

```
public interface AttributeService {
    void save(Attribute attribute);
    Attribute findById(int id);
    List<Attribute> findByName(String name);
    List<Attribute> findByObjectType(ObjectType objectType);
}
```

My AttributeServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
public class AttributeServiceImpl implements AttributeService {

    @Autowired
    private AttributeRepository attributeRepository;    

    public void save(Attribute attribute) {
        attributeRepository.save(attribute);
    }
    public Attribute findById(int id) {
        return attributeRepository.findById(id);
    }
    public List<Attribute> findByName(String name) {
        return attributeRepository.findByName(name);
    }
    public List<Attribute> findByObjectType(ObjectType objectType) {
        return attributeRepository.fidByObjectType(objectType);
    }
}
```

My Exception:

```
    <15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,550 AM EEST> <Error> <org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader> <BEA-000000> <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.shop.database.repositories.AttributeRepository com.shop.database.services.impl.AttributeServiceImpl.attributeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.shop.database.repositories.AttributeRepository com.shop.database.services.impl.AttributeServiceImpl.attributeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,561 AM EEST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.shop.database.repositories.AttributeRepository com.shop.database.services.impl.AttributeServiceImpl.attributeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.shop.database.repositories.AttributeRepository com.shop.database.services.impl.AttributeServiceImpl.attributeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.shop.database.repositories.AttributeRepository com.shop.database.services.impl.AttributeServiceImpl.attributeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'attributeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,608 AM EEST> <Warning> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2017-05-15 08:49:22.592--No partition instance associated with current SessionManager instance.> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,614 AM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "4217989485440" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,618 AM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9 task for the application "packear_ear" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,662 AM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "packear_ear".> 
<15 ìàÿ 2017, 8:49:22,663 AM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute:org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException:No property fid found for type com.shop.database.entities.Attribute
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: on doing what operation are you getting this exception. Do you have a Repository class and method which you are calling. Update your question with more details.

Comment: suppose you are missing the setter for `id`. and please share the full stack trace of the exception and it may be helpful.

Comment: Does the `LAB3_ATTRIBUTES` table have a `fid` column? Maybe it's trying to map the column to the object but you don't have a `fid` variable.

Comment: 1) This exception occurs when I try to build ear and deploy it. 2) I removed setter for id because it is generated automatically, but with setter present it is no difference too. 3) No, there no such field or variable as "fid" in entire project, it has to be some jpa/hibernate/sql naming or annotation issue I believe, but I cannot figure it out myself.

Comment: tima, you turned out to be right, actually. Thanx! Could you post your reply as an answer so I could confirm it? I searched for "fid" in my project and found that I mistyped one of my methods name. Instead of "findBy..." it was "fidBy..." and so according to naming convention spring didn't understand the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
List<Attribute> fidByObjectType(ObjectType objectType);
```

It should be

```
List<Attribute> findByObjectType(ObjectType objectType);
```

Due to the typo, Spring Data is looking for a property named "fid", which of course does not exist.